# Scroll to different id(s) from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different boxes with different id 
`<div id="49" align="center" class="feed_box_id"></div>`
`<div id="50" align="center" class="feed_box_id"></div>`
`<div id="51" align="center" class="feed_box_id"></div>`

 i want to scroll a next id whenever the *same* button is clicked.

I tried

- scrollTop
- scrollTo
- window.location.href

But couldn't find a way out. 
if you want, here is my *fuzzy code*

```
var id_down = parseInt($(".feed_box_id").attr("id")) - 1;

  $("#feed_down").click(function() {

     window.location.href = "#" + id_down; 

  });

  var id_up = parseInt($(".feed_box_id").attr("id")) + 1;

    $("#feed_up").click(function() {
     window.location.href = "#" + id_up; 

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a variable that keeps the track of the last clicked id.

```
var lastclicked={id:49};

$("#feed_up").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
    if($("#" + (e.data.id+1)).length>0)
    {
        window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id+1);
        e.data.id++;
    }
});
$("#feed_down").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
    if($("#" + (e.data.id-1)).length>0)
    {
        window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id-1);
        e.data.id--;
    }
});
```

Okay, you can create the fiddle by yourself.

HTML:

```
<button id="feed_down">feed_down</button>
<button id="feed_up">feed_up</button>
```

JS:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    $('<div id="' + (i) + '" align="center" class="feed_box_id">'+ (i) +'</div>').appendTo($('body'));
}

var lastclicked={id:49};

$("#feed_up").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
    if($("#" + (e.data.id+1)).length>0)
    {
        window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id+1);
        e.data.id++;
    }
});
$("#feed_down").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
    if($("#" + (e.data.id-1)).length>0)
    {
        window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id-1);
        e.data.id--;
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#feed_down
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0
}
#feed_up
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:100px
}
```

Comment: console showing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: Please check the edited code. `e.data.lastclicked.id` should be `e.data.id`.

Comment: But, now the location keeps adding and subtracting. `http://localhost/#53` `http://localhost/#40` , which doesn't even exist.

Comment: Wrap the code in an `if` statement to check if the anchor exists.

Comment: Sorry, i don't play much with javascript, would you just give me an example again and for the records i am using div

Comment: No problem. All you have to do is check if the anchor with the specified ID exists before jumping onto it.

So instead of doing `$("#feed_up").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id+1); 
e.data.id++;
}`
you can first verify using 
`$("#feed_up").click(lastclicked, function(e) {
    if($("#" + (e.data.id+1)).length>0)
    {
        window.location.href = "#" + (e.data.id+1);
        e.data.id++;
    }
});`

I've updated the answer which should work.

Comment: sorry but, now nothing's happening ?

Comment: But, the fiddle is blank!

Comment: JSFiddle isn't saving the code properly.

You can use the instructions I've added in the answer.

**PS. Make sure to add jQuery 1.7+ support from the left menubar**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways: using only class without ids, using ids and no class is needed.
Class only:

```
var elementIndex = 0, elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var scrollToElement = function(element){
    window.scrollTo(0, element.getBoundingClientRect().top);
};
var nextElement = function(){
    if(++elementIndex >= elements.length)
        elementIndex = 0;
    scrollToElement(elements[elementIndex]);
};
var previousElement = function(){
    if(--elementIndex < 0)
        elementIndex = elements.length - 1;
    scrollToElement(elements[elementIndex]);
};
```

Id only (may be not only numbers):

```
var elementIndex = 0, elements = ['id1', 'myDog', 'last'];
var scrollToElement = function(element){
    window.scrollTo(0, element.getBoundingClientRect().top);
};
var nextElement = function(){
    if(++elementIndex >= elements.length)
        elementIndex = 0;
    scrollToElement(document.getElementById(elements[elementIndex]));
};
var previousElement = function(){
    if(--elementIndex < 0)
        elementIndex = elements.length - 1;
    scrollToElement(document.getElementById(elements[elementIndex]));
};
```